# RESTORE is not restoring database in its original state

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a backup file (~9Gb, can't modify) under SQL Server 2012, and frequently have to restore my base to its original state, but I've noticed the .ldf log file is getting really huge (>20Gb today) whereas the first time it was aroung 1Gb.

I've tried to shrink log file and limit log file size, but still restoring at 20Gb the next time, I've deleted database and cleared msdb restore history and still restoring a huge .ldf file....

I'm using the code:

> USE [master]
>
> RESTORE DATABASE [MYBASE] FROM  DISK = N'D:\SQLServer\BACKUP\MYBACKUP.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,
>
> MOVE N'MYBACKUP' TO N'D:\SQLServer\DATA\MYBASE.mdf',
>
> MOVE N'MYBACKUP' TO N'D:\SQLServer\LOG\MYBASE.ldf',
>
> NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
>
> GO

Any ideas ?

Is there something wrong on my code ?

Comment: Provide context - you notice the huge log file when? Immediately after restoring? If so, then you (or someone else) has overwritten your backup with the "small" log file with one having a large log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is any other possibility than shrinking the log file after the restore.

The question you should wonder about is why the logfile is getting so big. Very often this is the case when the recovery mode is set to "Full", but no logfile backups are made, or at least very infrequent, or when there are large batch operations on the database (e.g. large imports) - in the last case, a large logfile is needed, but the file size does not reflect the amount of data in the logfile. Shrinking it has the side effect that when it is growing, it needs more disk I/O to grow the log file, and this affects performance.

Another reason could be that the logfile autogrowth value is set to a percentage value. Therefore each grow step is bigger than the one before. It could help using a MB value, say 50 MB instead of 10% for example (but this really depends on your needs, don't take these values as optimal for your case).

Best wishes
Michael

Comment: Thanks, I've restored the database, set the recovery mode to simple, shrunk log file, and backed up this edited database. This new backup has the same data but the log file does not grow up anymore after a restore :)

Comment: Please note that simple recovery mode can only be used when you only make full backups. That means, when you backup your database one time a day, you have no chance to restore the database at a time after the last backup. I don't want to talk too much about backup strategies here in this comment, but please go ahead and try to understand the difference between "full" and "simple" recovery model, and the terms "database backup" (or "full backup") and "logfile backup".